# Stack overflow exception error in R script method for subsequent request

Tags: c#, r

When I call R script method from Web API it is working for first request it returns the result, but for subsequent request getting Stack overflow exception.
The same code is working on another system, tried desposing all the objects in the R.

Please help me to sort out this issue.
Using R 3.4.2 version.

WebAPI Method calling R Script:

```
Public HttpResponseMessage CallTestMethod()
{
    // SetupPath(); setting Rpackage and ODBC package paths in environment no issue with this method.
    REngine engine;
    engine = REngine.GetInstance();
    //Mentioned R Script file path
    var val = engine.Evaluate("source('C:/Folder/RProject1/Script.R')");
    //Call FetchDatawithoutParam () and get data frame values in dsResult .
    var dsResult = engine.Evaluate(@"TempDataResult <- FetchDatawithoutParam ()").AsDataFrame();
}
```

R Script function as below:

```
FetchDatawithoutParam <- function() {

    dbConnection <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=.;database=DBName;trusted_connection=true')
    DataResult <- sqlQuery(dbConnection, "SELECT * FROM TableName;")
    return(DataResult );

    odbcClose(dbConnection)
}
```

Comment: Do the 2 computers install with same SQL server ODBC driver version? Please double check

Comment: Yes ODBC driver Version: 1.3-15